# simple_form is giving error undefined method `reviews_path' for #<# for nested route in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, nested-routes

I checked the other simple_form posts and they didn't quite hit on my problem. I have a nested resource for restaurant reviews in my routes.rb here:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :restaurants do
    resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index]
   end
```

My review controller seems to be set properly here:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_restaurant
  before_action :set_review, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /reviews/new
  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

  # GET /reviews/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /reviews
  # POST /reviews.json
  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.restaurant_id = @restaurant.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Review was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @review }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.update(review_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @review, notice: 'Review was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @review }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reviews/1
  # DELETE /reviews/1.json
  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reviews_url, notice: 'Review was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end
    def set_restaurant
      @restuarant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    end
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment)
    end
end
```

My restaurant controller is here:

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_restaurant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /restaurants
  # GET /restaurants.json
  def index
    @restaurants = Restaurant.all
  end

  # GET /restaurants/1
  # GET /restaurants/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /restaurants/new
  def new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new
  end

  # GET /restaurants/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /restaurants
  # POST /restaurants.json
  def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @restaurant.save
        format.html { redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @restaurant }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /restaurants/1
  # PATCH/PUT /restaurants/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @restaurant.update(restaurant_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @restaurant }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /restaurants/1
  # DELETE /restaurants/1.json
  def destroy
    @restaurant.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to restaurants_url, notice: 'Restaurant was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_restaurant
      @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def restaurant_params
      params.require(:restaurant).permit(:name, :address, :phone, :website, :image)
    end
end
```

and my simple_form_for is super straight forward:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@restaurant, @review] do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :rating %>
    <%= f.input :comment %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So, I don't know why I am getting this error :(

Comment: add the full error with the log, please.

Comment: Can you show what your `new` method within the controller looks like? The error undefined method `reviews_path` is coming from the `new` page where you are displaying the form. Unless if your `create` method has a redirect_to @review.

Comment: Though it's probably your typo in `@restaurant` thats causing the problem, in whatever controller it is.

Comment: @kittyminky2 I updated my post to reflect my full reviews and restaurant controllers. I don't think the `new` method has a redirect.

Comment: @sevenseacat I've been trying to figure out how to access logs actually. I am not sure how to do it. I do however, have `better errors` gem enabled and it is telling me that it is having an issue with `polymorphic routes`. I updated my post to reflect the full controllers though so take a look. I appreciate any feedback, thanks!

Comment: the logs will be displayed in the terminal you started your rails server in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the value of `@restaurant` which since you mispelled it as `@restuarant` will not work.

Comment: How silly of me, thank you! I think I must have been staring at the screen too long haha